# Google Analytics automation using Selenium webdriver

Tags: google-analytics

I am doing automation of GA using Selenium web driver. The issue I am facing is sometimes when I trigger the events from Selenium web driver are getting recorded on GA and sometimes they don’t. The behavior is totally random of which events get showed up on GA real time. I do see the Active user increments under Events so that means the script is talking to GA.

Comment: What does "GAvuding" mean (I assume it is a typo) ?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.